# Angular5 How to open external url in modal dialog

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using Angular5 in my project and I was looking into angular's material to show a modal dialog in my application.

I was able to implement the dialog and I could display my project's components in the dialog, however I could not find a way to open an external url into the modal. I have some old external webpages that are not going to be converted to Angular5 and I need to interact with these pages from my angular app.

This is the current sample

```
let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogTestComponent, {
  width: '400px',
  data: config
});
```

Is there a way to open an url like

```
let dialogRef = this.dialog.open('https://localhost/test', {
  width: '400px',
  data: config
});
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Could you create a component where all it does is render a url (perhaps via an iframe) and then call dialog.open with that component with the url passed in the data parameter?

Comment: Yeah I was going to suggest the same thing as bob

Comment: I was thinking in doing that but I was not sure if it was a nice way to do it :) Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: There is no other way than using an iframe, if you want to render an arbitrary other site in your modal. So yes, it is "a nice way" to do it, since it's the only way to do it :)